# Get count of Facebook Connect logins to site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-authentication

What is the best way to get a count of how many times users have used the Facebook Connect login button ([this thing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)) to login to a site?

I have read through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ to no avail. I don't have access to the Facebook API set up yet, but perhaps that provides a count of logins?

Comment: Count these locally. The API won't give you information about your site. Don't you have code that serves different content to logged in users vs. unknowns?

Comment: Thanks... that's what we are currently doing for internal log ins to our site. I was hoping for a way to verify the DB counts we're getting for logins via Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your og tags set up properly:

```
fb:app_id - A Facebook Platform application ID that administers this page.
```

More info on that here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

The Insights tab on your facebook app will give you the information you seek. Keep in mind though, that the data may be 48 hours behind.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am familiar with the data provided by Insights and don't see a login in count as one of the metrics. Definitely let me know otherwise!

Comment: Go to the Users portion. This will give you Daily, Weekly, Monthly... if that is the only way for users to access the app.